# Python: Pass a function with parameters to a function

Tags: python

I really am not sure if im missing something extremely basic but im trying to pass a function another function with parameters without executing it.

```
def movePaddle(paddle, direction):
    y = paddle.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle.sety(y)
```

The movePaddle function takes a paddle and a direction. i want to bind this to the onkeypress function of turtle.

```
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(movepaddle(paddleA, "up"), "w")
```

Running above code would execute the movepaddle function once. which is obviously not the desired behaviour. The desired behaviour is that whenever the onkeypress eventhandler encounters a "w" key. it executes the movepaddle function with the given "paddleA" and "up" parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `functools.partial`

The `partial` function receives a function and parameters, and returns a callable that calls the supplied function with the given parameters.

```py
import functools

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(functools.partial(movepaddle, paddleA, "up")), "w")
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: That works, is it just me or is it really wierd that you can just pass the entire function as an argument. I have never seen a usecase where i wanted a parameter to execute instantly.

Comment: So in my opinion there are 3 main use cases: The first and obvious is just calling a function with the result of another function, for example `print(len("Hello")`. The second one is just passing a callback function that receives arguments (like most lambda functions) and the third one is your case, when you want the callback to be called with specific, predefined paramters. In the last case, An object with the function and the arguments is created, and its `__call__` method just calls the function with the supplied parameters.